# NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.ImageView.setPivotX

Tags: android, android-imageview

While setting the pivotx for my imageview I am getting the following error during run time:

10-06 03:27:28.190: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(327): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.ImageView.setPivotX

What does this mean?As far as I know setPivotX is a valid method for an imageview..

Here is the code:

```
private void updateRotation(double angle)
{

   mTop.setPivotX(mTop.getWidth()/2);
   mTop.setPivotY(mTop.getHeight()/2);
   mTop.setRotation(180);

}
```

Comment: Yes it is. Please post a fragment of code here.

Comment: @AVD For my App minSDKVersion is 8.I have added the code in the question itself:-

Comment: You must choose API level 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPivotX%28float%29) `setPivotX` is only available on API Level 11 (Android 3.0). You must be running on a device/emulator with an earlier version.